# Trying to display two concatenated variables in email subject line using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to display two concatenated variables in a subject line through an mailer.php page, but the subject line in the email always comes in blank.  Below is the pertinent code.

```
/* Subject and To */

$to = 'nnorman@dimplexthermal.com';
$subject = $company . ' ' . $name;

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Company: $company <br>

EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$to = 'nnorman@dimplexthermal.com';
$subject = $company . ' ' . $name;

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
```

You're not setting `$company` and `$name` until after you use them in `$subject`

Try switching the lines round:

```
/* Gathering Data Variables */

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];

$to = 'nnorman@dimplexthermal.com';
$subject = $company . ' ' . $name;
```